# Using indexers VS inheriting from ArrayList or List<T>?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a library to use in a card game. I spent a couple of hours learning indexers so I could have a Deck class that functions like an array of Card types. Then I achieved the same thing and a whole lot more by inheriting from ArrayList. I therefore ask why one would go to the trouble of making a class indexable when the same thing (and much more) can be achieved via ": ArrayList".

I think my question is pretty self explanatory, but for those who like to look at code.

Here is my Deck class that contains an indexer:

```
class DeckIndexer
{
    private Card[] myData;
    private int arrSize;



public DeckIndexer(int size)
{
    arrSize = size;
    myData = new Card[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        myData[i] = null;
    }
}

public Card this[int pos]
{
    get
    {
        return myData[pos];
    }
    set
    {
        myData[pos] = value;
    }
}

public Card this[Card c]
{
    get
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
        {
            if (myData[i] == c)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
    set
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
        {
            if (myData[i] == c)
            {
                myData[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now here is the second solution, inheriting from ArrayList

```
  class DeckInheritence : ArrayList
  {

  }
```

The second solution gives me 20+ methods for free, [] syntax, and saves me however many lines of code. The first gives me [] syntax, the methods attached to object, and is hard to implement.

BTW, yes I can see that ArrayList is giving me an array of objects, not cards, but there is not much fudging to get it to require a Card type.

Comment: `arrSize` can be replaced with `myData.Length`, no need to have it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, unless you are in .NET 1.1, `List<Card>` would be preferable. However, as for inheriting... if all you are doing is representing a list of cards, I would **just use** `List<Card>` (with neither encapsulation nor inheritance).

As for the *why*; encapsulation is useful when *being a list* is not the primary purpose of a type, but it is useful for the caller to have access to a few methods like indexers. As Jon notes, *inheriting* doesn't (for example) give you any control over what the user **does** to your data.

Personally, I don't recommend inheriting from `List<T>` (or `ArrayList`); that binds an implementation detail into the actual type declaration (changing inheritance is a breaking change).

If you want to expose lots of methods with minimal work, all you need to do is provide `IEnumerable<T>` (as an interface) - then all of LINQ becomes available. So **if** you need something bespoke (more than `List<Card>`) my advice would be:

- *encapsulate* `List<T>` (i.e. a private field)
- *implement* `IEnumerable<T>` if appropriate  (just return `theList.GetEnumerator()`)
- add any specific members you want (indexers etc)

Comment: OK. I'll try just that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally a `Deck` is *not* an `ArrayList` or a `List<Card>`. Do you want callers to be able to add as many cards as they want to it? I doubt it. How about null or duplicate values? Again, unlikely to be useful.

This is a perfect situation for using composition instead of inheritance. I wouldn't use an array directly within the type - I'd use a `List<T>` - but you almost certainly want to write more domain-specific code for your deck. There are obvious constraints, deck-specific operations etc. Do you really want to be able to access *any* item in the deck? I would expect you to want to be able to deal a deck to players, and shuffle it, for example.

The goal should be to create a type which represents your domain as appropriately as possible - not to give you an indexer with the fewest lines of code.

Comment: Interesting advice Jon. I'll meditate on that heh. I'm not really at the stage in my programming yet where I think too much about preventing what an object can do. I guess I just figure if I don't need the methods I wont use them heh. Of course I am the only one who uses my classes so that's probably why I have a misguided view. Thanks.